# Mirror of men! he showers, with liberal hands,

Tags: cipher

lxwhmlnv lhlib mxbwhmlnv lbnJ

---

*I wonder how long it will take, should not be too difficult, but not to easy either.
Please let me know in your answer what you think of the difficulty and if it's "fun", I'm going to make a lot more and want some feedback to make them better.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answer

> "Who will guard the guards themselves?"/"Who watches the watchers?"

Step 1:

> The string is backwards. Reverse it to get "Jnbl vnlmhwbxm bilhl vnlmhwxl"

Step 2:

> Perform Rot7 on the string (A->H, B->I, etc.) to get "Quis custodiet ipsos custodes". (Note: I found this by doing Rot1 seven times.)

Step 3:

> ["Quis custodiet ipsos custodes"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quis_custodiet_ipsos_custodes%3F) is Latin for "Who will guard the guards themselves?" The phrase comes from Juvenal's [Satires](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satires_(Juvenal)).

Explanation of title:

> The title is a quote from one of Juvenal's other satires.

What I thought of the puzzle:

> It was fun, but fairly obvious - the last letter made step 1 obvious, and the encryption used in step 2 is fairly weak. If the string is more than just a word or two, the frequency and distribution of letters still looks like normal words (just not actual words), strongly suggesting to check that specific form of encryption.

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain, please don't name answers in comments. And yes this was the answer, the title was to help you search for the poem which was in juvenal's satire number VII (so 7)

Comment: @VincentAdvocaat, I have deleted my comment.  Sorry about that.  I should have said that the Step 2 solution was the intended solution.

Comment: Next one will be more difficult seeing this was a bit too easy. @GentlePurpleRain yes that is better for next time, no worries ;)

Comment: @rob, did you simply brute force it with rot until you got 7, why did you use rot? Could you add this to your answr?

Comment: @VincentAdvocaat just added it.

Comment: well it was ceasar 7 since the guy who wrote the poem from the titel is roman, so roman -> ceasar. And it was 7 since the quote was his seventh poem, next time i'll use a better cipher, also i took tah specific quote since it had the word mirror suggesting your step 1 ;)

Comment: The cluing of mirroring and Caesar was nice, though obscure enough that it is liable to be figured out by trial and error instead. Despite the cluing, composing well-known ciphers makes for a dry puzzle. Try something more ambitious. See [this meta post](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/1717/4551).