# difficile est saturam non legere

Tags: riddle, cipher, language

Well, [my last question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/12181/mirror-of-men-he-showers-with-liberal-hands) wasn't received that well, nevertheless I will make a better one, besides you will need all the answers you can get.

**vcejssnr**

Now I can't leave you with a stupid cryptogram and another strange title, can I?
I did that one time, this time it's not that simple because what I am looking for cannot be described in words. It is however, the answer in more ways than one.

**Hint #1**

> My words are well chosen, mistakes are **never** made.

**Hint #2**

> This one time I will layout the pad before you.

**Hint #3**

> The previous question is more useful than you might think

**Hint #4**

> If you know vcejssnr then something in the previous question must be familiar, if not google.

**Hint #5**

> the answer is the driving factor for the entirety of the story

**If you take away anything from this puzzle let it be that**

> **the book mentioned in the answer is worth a read :)**

Comment: What you're looking for can be described in words. Try "a picture", "a number", "a word", "a set of letters", "a philosophical concept", etc.

Comment: O seriously, why do I get a down vote? at least tell me so I can do something about it? :'(

Comment: "difficile est saturam non scribere" (It's difficult not to write a satire) is contained in Juvenal's works, like in your last question. You changed "scribere" meaning "to write" to "legere" meaning "to read". I don't know.. somehow "scribere" has similar letters to "vcejssnr" which we can rearrange to "scrjvers". EDIT: j/i, v/b, s/e are close on my qwerty keyboard x).

Comment: Sneaky downvoters are a known issue here in Puzzling. Btw, this puzzle doesn't seem stupid, I upvoted it.

Comment: @leoll2 I think part of the downvote situation here relates to this question: http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/1717/code-puzzles-what-not-to-do/1719#1719. It seems like a puzzle with very few hints, so it's not well-received.

Comment: @BenFrankel I think Elon Musk's responce to his falcon 9 rocket problem suits you very well ;)

Comment: @mdc32 fair enough, the linked examples are extremely nice but i think if people knew this isn't just a silly decrypt this (aka if they wouldn't jump to rash conclusions) they'd figure not everything is what it seems ;)

But thank you for sharing a reason and a possibility for me to improve on :)

Comment: @leoll2 what is a good time to give hints? every 24 hours? more? less?

Comment: It depends on the difficulty of the problem, anyway 1 hint every 24 hours is appropriate for each kind of puzzle, in my opinion!

Comment: @VincentAdvocaat, re hints, I suggest waiting to see how much progress people make on solving it.

Comment: Well apparently nothing, I'd expect someone to at least mention they've gotten half way (deciphering the cryptogram). But not even that has been done for as far as I can tell of course. but @AE I'll do 1 hint every day, (seeing as I'm super impatient) :P

Comment: @VincentAdvocaat - Fyi, stackexchange policy discourages comments within the question. However you are welcome to make the same comments in the comment section below the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cryptogram decodes to:

> **danbrown**
>
> which results from the cipher text of **vcejssnr** and a key (one time pad) of **scribere**

So, the answer to the riddle could be:

> **the number 3**
>
> In Dan Brown's novel, the **Digital Fortress** is the name of a new encryption algorithm that cannot be broken by the NSA. This relates to the **one time pad** encryption method that, also, cannot be broken when properly used.
>
> Another link is the quote from the previous question "Quis custodiet ipsos custodes?" which was used in this novel.  As described in the previous question, this sentence was written by the Roman poet, Juvenal, in his **Satires** collection of poems (which also relates to the title of this question).
>
> Assuming that "cannot be described in words" means that "the answer is a number", then the number **3** is most significant in this novel. The kill code for the virus was 3.

Comment: not bad, try to incorporate the previous answer more.

Comment: btw how did you get YHWH?

Comment: Oww nice word, it's new to me but seems a bit to literal, in the comments Ian MacDonald gave a good indication of what it might be.

Comment: Oww verry nice, but i wouldn't let the answer depend on dutch, no yhe thing i'm looking for is a number (cannot be described in words) but you've got the correct book though ;)

Comment: why would it be guess the number? the answer to the question in digital fortress can only be 3, there is no other number of significance, it's the driver of the whole plot the answer to the ultimate question of that book. so no it's not guess what i am thinking, The only thing I'd like to think is that my clues were sufficient to get to that answer.

Comment: @VincentAdvocaat - OK, I agree.  For me, the weakness is the linkage between "cannot be described in words" and "the answer is a number" because that clue could mean so many different things or taken literally, could be almost nothing because everything can be described by words.

Comment: True, that's my kryptonite, over dramatifying things :P