# The queen of riddles

Tags: riddle, knowledge, rhyme

> Every good story is build up of acts, 
>   one of which is a tragedy,
>   they all convey a mystery,
>   how many there are is history,
>   by the time you know your destiny.

$ $

> Destined for greatness destined for good,
>   you must be the best, pulling stories from your hood,
>   murder is something you truly understood.

**Who am I?**

*I was originally going to post this as a follow up [to my last question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/12276/difficile-est-saturam-non-legere) but I found the riddle to be solvable without, the answer would be a good extra hint for the first paragraph though.*

Nevertheless here's an other **hint** for the first paragraph if you desperately need it:

> Setup, Confrontation, Resolution

**EDIT:**
Please note there is an answer to the first paragraph, which will help you find who I am in the 2nd paragraph.

Comment: I guess the first paragraph starts with "every" and ends with "destiny", while the 2nd is from "Destined" to "understood", right?

Comment: correct, you might even split it up further (first 2 lines and the next 3 lines) but together they form a description. and who am I should be taken literally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the answer is

> Agatha Christie

Every good story is build up of acts,

> She's a writer and knows how to build suspense

one of which is a tragedy,

> Mystery novels almost always have a murder or something else bad happen

they all convey a mystery,

> She's a mystery writer

how many there are is history,

> She's dead and therefore the number of books she's written is set

by the time you know your destiny.

> I'm not quite sure about this one. She's wrote a book called "Destination Unknown"

Destined for greatness destined for good,/you must be the best, pulling stories from your hood,

> She's widely considered to be one of the best mystery authors and is one of the top published authors of all time

murder is something you truly understood.

> She wrote murder mysteries

As to the "Queen of Riddles"

> Her a mystery is very similar to a riddle and many readers try to solve her stories as they read them

Comment: Almost perfect, there is actually a book: three act tragedy ;) and she is named the queen of mystery or queen of crime, like you said riddles and mystery are closely related

Answer (score 2):

Every good story is build up of acts,

> Some kind of play?

one of which is a tragedy,

> Greek tragedy maybe?

they all convey a mystery,
how many there are is history,
by the time you know your destiny.

> Each act conveys a new mystery, but by the time every mystery is solved it is already too late. Maybe Oedipus?

Destined for greatness destined for good,

> Destined to become a King, which he did by defeating the sphinx

you must be the best, pulling stories from your hood,

> A reference to answering the sphinx's riddles?

murder is something you truly understood.

> It's revealed he killed his father and married his mother at the end of the play.

The title of the post points there as well,

> 'the queen' referring to his mother/wife and 'of riddles' to the sphinx.

Comment: nice one but alas no, if queen in the title refers to who i am doesn't that person need to be a woman? also pulling stories from a hood isn't really the same as answering riddles, pulling stories from a hood (like the phrase from a hat) indicates a bit of nonchalance like making things up, when answering a riddle you don't make things up. But keep trying :) also to me it seems like Greek comes out of nowhere. Thinking to first look for a book was good (first act) then thinking to find a person connected to the book as well (final act).

Comment: Yeah, the 'pulling stories from your hood' bit was my main worry. The Greek bit comes from the fact that there are 2 (primary) types of Greek plays, tragedies and comedies.

Comment: oke I did not know that thanks :) but yeh.. :P

Answer (score 2):

The answer may be

> Lady Macbeth (Queen of Scotland, as hinted in the title).  I'm not terribly familiar with Shakespeare, but I'll see if I can explain these clues.

Every good story is build up of acts,

> All of Shakespeare's plays are divided into acts.

one of which is a tragedy,

> Macbeth is a tragedy.

they all convey a mystery,

> They all build up towards the final act.

how many there are is history,
by the time you know your destiny.

> By the time you get to the end of a play, you know how many acts there are.

Destined for greatness destined for good,

> The three witches prophesized that Macbeth would be King (and therefore she would be Queen).

you must be the best, pulling stories from your hood,
murder is something you truly understood.

> She helped plot the murder of King Duncan.

Comment: Wow very good never thought about this one, it fits like a glove except for the queen of riddles part, she is queen but i don't see how the riddles fit in. Also she does not shake stories from her hood. But definitely worth a few up votes, here take one

Comment: "The queen of riddles" isn't part of the riddle. Are we supposed to infer that it is based on the title alone? That seems awkward.

Comment: No but it was said as the title suggest so if you say it's correct because of the title you should incorporate the whole title, that was more my point :p obviously the title isn't needed to complete the riddle but it is able to validate your answer. But either incorporate the whole of the title if you use it as argument :)